# PHPUnit: ignore specific directory in testSuite

Tags: phpunit

I'm trying to test all directories except from one in a specific folder. My current tree:

```
app/code/My/Module/Test/SomeTest.php
app/code/Magento/Admin/Test/SomeTest.php
app/code/Other/Module/Test/AnotherTest.php
```

I need to run all tests but those inside the `app/code/Magento` directory. What I've tried so far:

```
<testsuite name="Modules Tests">
    <directory suffix=".php">app/code/*/*/Test</directory>
    <exclude>app/code/Magento</exclude>
</testsuite>
```

Even using exclude with absolute path or a wildcard `app/code/Magento/*`, they keep being added to testsuite. Also tried with blacklist, but it seems to be ignored as well.

I'm using PHPUnit 4.6.4.

Any advice here?

Thanks!

Comment: The testsuite exclude tag behavior doesn't seem to be that well documented, but it seems to be only excluding test files from the specified path (and not from subfolders under that path) - at least for 4.1.0 version this seems to be the case. I.e. you could try with '<exclude>app/code/Magento/Admin/Test</exclude>'

Comment: @ejuhjav Thanks. This is the exact behavior right now. Won't solve my problem but allows me to have a better understanding.

Answer (score -1):

See the working example [here](https://gist.github.com/EvanK/7553935).
Also 'exclude are ignored if a path is added within the command line' according to the comment in the link.